# Связи associated в Cake PHP 3.6

Tags: php, cakephp

использую плагин `CakeDC`. хочу к таблице `users` привязать другую таблицу `player_heroes`. в редактирование профиля добавил поле

```
$this->Form->select('PlayerHeroes.hero', $heroes, 
            ['multiple' => true,
             'id'=>'fav-hero-select'
             ]);
```

в `action` контроллера добавил

```
$entity = $table->patchEntity($entity, $this->request->getData(), ['associated'=>['PlayerHeroes']]);
if ($table->save($entity)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__d('CakeDC/Users', 'The {0} has been saved', $singular));}
```

в `Entity\Users.php` прописал `hasMany` (`uid` поле в таблице `player_heroes`)

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('username');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.Register');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.Password');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.AuthFinder');            
        $this->hasMany('PlayerHeroes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'uid']);
    }
```

После сохранения профиля таблица `users` обновляется, а `player_heroes` пуста. Может дело в путях? `Users` находится в `vendor/cakedc/src/`, а `PlayerHeroes` в корне `app/src/`. Никаких ошибок не выбивает

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать множественный выбор, то вам нужна связь `belongsToMany` и промежуточная таблица для ее хранения. Если эта связь еще сама по себе представлена сущностью, то для этого есть опция `through` в конфиге.

Comment: и в имени поля, возможно потребуется указать полный путь `select("Users.PlayersHeroes.hero")`, хотя для селектов обычно пишут `._ids` если у вас выбор  чекбоксами. в общем мне не совсем ясно что и как вы вообще хотите связать и редактировать

Comment: `associated` в `patch` прописывают, когда хотят изменить сами связанные данные. если вам только связь сохранить надо, это не нужно. Так что проясните, что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать

Comment: есть таблица users, я хочу в таблицу player_heroes добавить строки - у одного игрока может быть несколько героев, т.е. users hasMany player_heroes. когда игрок правит профиль, я хочу из мультиселекта добавлять/удалять строки из таблицы player_heroes

Comment: один черт не ясно. вариант 1) У вас есть  уже список героев, с которым вы хотите настраивать связи, поэтому у вас множественный селект с чекбоксами. В таком случае вам нужна связь `belongsToMany` и селект для `_ids`. Вариант 2) вы хотите прям создавать героев для пользователя. Но тогда вам нужны не селект с галками, а инпуты для ввода имен героев, и тогда, да, вам в `patchEntity` нужны `associated` Мне кажется нужен вам вариант 1 - со связью многие ко многим. Каждый пользователь может выбрать нескольких героев общего списка, и герой может быть выбран несколькими пользователями.

Comment: да. есть список героев (таблица heroes), из неё делается список для мультиселекта. почему belongsToMany если игрок Один, а героев Много? и я не пойму, что такое _ids

Comment: у вас один единственный пользователь во всей системе? или их все же несколько может быть?

Comment: пользователей много, но belongsToMany это извращение по моему, из примера: "Примером отношения «один ко многим» является статья в блоге, которая имеет «много» комментариев.", но статья то не одна на сайте...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76583/discussion-between-ke1evra-and-teran).

Comment: да, но конкретный комментарий то относится к единственной статье. поэтому у комментария в таблице есть `post_id`, ссылающийся  на эту единственную статью.  У вас же одного героя может выбрать несколько пользователей. поэтому это связь многие-ко-многим, реализуется через доп таблицу (`heroes_users (id, user_id, hero_id)`), где сохраняются пары id пользователь-герой, обозначающие кто и кого выбрал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подытожу дискуссию в комментариях.

У нас имеется: таблицы `Users` и таблица `Heroes` и мы хотим связать их, так что бы при редактировании пользователя мы могли выбрать несколько значений `heroes`.

Данная связь описывается отношением `многие-ко-многим`, и реализуется с помощью `belongsToMany`. Согласно [соглашениям об именовании](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions) в cakephp, таблица связи должна назыаться, используя имена связуемых таблицы в алфавитном порядке, и иметь ключи по названиям таблиц в единственном числе с суффиксом `_id`.

Таким образом, для реализации связи нужна таблица `heroes_users` с полями `id,  user_id, hero_id`.

У вас же таблица связи (`players_heroes`) уже создана, и имеет структуру `id, uid, heroid`. Что заставляет нас вручную конфигурировать связь.

*Помимо этого при использовании имен, не соответствующих принятым правилам именования, лишает вас возможности нормально генерировать классы таблицы и моделей с помощью `cake bake model`.*

В итоге, требуется настроить таблицу `Users` следующим образом:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Heroes', [ 
              'joinTable' => 'players_heroes',
              'foreignKey' => 'uid',
              'targetForeignKey' => 'heroid'
         ]);
```

и теперь в шаблоне редактирования осталось вывести

```
$this->Form->select("heroes._ids", $heroes, ['multiple' => true]);
```

где `$heroes` это список полученный с помощью

```
 $ht = TableRegistry::get('default');
 $heroes = $ht->find('list')->toArray();
```

Приведенного кода достаточно для сохранения связей многие-ко-многим.

---

В дополнение, в приведенном вами коде фигурирует еще две вещи.

1. сущность `PlayerHeroes`. Для простого сохранения связи она не нужна. Необходимость в таком возникает, когда помимо самого факта *выбора* нужно хранить и доп. информацию. Например, кроме выбора важен еще и запомнить порядок, либо какого то героя пометить как `favorites`. Тогда таблица `players_heroes` дополняется новыми столбцами, создается отдельная сущность для этой таблицы, и при конфигурации добавляется опция `through`, указывающая а класс этой связующей таблицы.
2. `associated` в `patchEntity`. Опять же, для простого сохранения связи это не нужно. Этот параметр может использоваться когда мы, например, одновременно с сохранением связи,  решим еще и переименовать героя.